# Concurrent Threadpool error from testng , after initializing the driver , driver spons for a sec and then it dies with below error

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, testng

i am using `testng` to run my testcases written in `Java` but  its failing by giving this error.
As a lack of developing knowledge i am unable to find out the exact root cause of following **error :**

> [2013-11-11 08:31:57,401] ERROR PoolService-0 com.zycus.testautomation.common.Utility afterExecutionOfTestcase - Logout Failed =>java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null
>        [java] java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null
>        [java]     at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:235)
>        [java]     at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap.of(ImmutableBiMap.java:61)
>        [java]     at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(ImmutableMap.java:80)
>        [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:276)
>        [java]     at com.zycus.testautomation.common.LoginLogoutUtil.iAnalyzeLogout(LoginLogoutUtil.java:92)
>        [java]     at com.zycus.testautomation.common.Utility.afterExecutionOfTestcase(Utility.java:1256)
>        [java]     at com.zycus.testautomation.ianalyze.testcase.ABCPartTwo.checkUnsavedReportPopUp(ABCPartTwo.java:202)
>        [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>        [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
>        [java]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
>        [java]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
>        [java]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:73)
>        [java]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:14)
>        [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

A little help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the source?

Comment: Looks like your error is happening in "com.zycus.testautomation.common.LoginLogoutUtil.iAnalyzeLogout", if you can post the code, we can advice you....